# Cannot use 'plot' in local scope Pinescript

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

When I try to save below script in pinescript

```
//@version=5
indicator("Elliott Waves", overlay=true)

       
        // Check if the current wave is complete
        current_wave_length += 1
        if current_wave_length >= wave_length
            // Calculate the wave amplitude
            wave_amplitude = get_wave_amplitude()
            // Check if the wave amplitude is within the specified range
            if wave_amplitude >= wave_amp
                // Plot the wave
                if wave_direction == 1
                    plot(last_wave_low, color=color.green)
                    plot(current_wave_high, color=color.green)
                else
                    plot(last_wave_high, color=color.red)
                    plot(current_wave_low, color=color.red)
                    
    // Draw the current wave
    if current_wave_length > 0 and i == bar_index
        if wave_direction == 1
            plot(current_wave_low, color=color.green)
        else
            plot(current_wave_high, color=color.red)
```

I get an error:

> (Error at 60:21) Cannot use 'plot' in local scope
> (Error at 61:21) Cannot use 'plot' in local scope
> (Error at 63:21) Cannot use 'plot' in local scope
> (Error at 64:21) Cannot use 'plot' in local scope
> (Error at 81:13) Cannot use 'plot' in local scope
> (Error at 83:13) Cannot use 'plot' in local scope

Answer (score 0):

You cant use the plot function within an if statement. It has to be in the global scope. You need to do something like this instead.

```
plot(wave_amplitude >= wave_amp ? last_wave_low : na, color = color.green)
```